# How can I hyperlink the last letter in a Quill editor?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, quill

I have the following code (also on jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/96ye4hL4/1/ )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="editor0"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const quill = new Quill("#editor0", {
          modules: { toolbar: true },
          theme: "snow"
        });
        quill.setContents({"ops":[{"insert":"Index"},{"attributes":{"header":1},"insert":"\n"},{"attributes":{"link":"http://google.com"},"insert":"FooM"},{"insert":"\n"},{"insert":"\n"}]},)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the right most character in a hyperlink (the M in FooM), the hyperlink window does not pop up.

How can I pop up the hyperlink window upon clicking the last letter in FooM?

Answer (score 0):

This is an `open issue` with the Quill library.

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1931

Notice your code snippet will not run, but standard HREF does:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="editor0"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          const quill = new Quill("#editor0", {
              modules: { toolbar: true },
              theme: "snow"
            });
            quill.setContents({"ops":[{"insert":"Index"},{"attributes":{"header":1},"insert":"\n"},{"attributes":{"link":"http://google.com"},"insert":"FooM"},{"insert":"\n"},{"insert":"\n"}]},)
        </script>
        
        <a href= "http://google.com">FooM</a>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't think the issue you linked to relates to the problem I'm having. Am I missing something? Thank you.